# Extracting Javascript gettext messages using Babel CLI extractor

Tags: javascript, python, localization, gettext, python-babel

It is stated [here](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/messages.html) that Babel can extract gettext messages for Python and Javascript files.

> Babel comes with a few builtin extractors: python (which extracts
>   messages from Python source files), javascript, and ignore (which
>   extracts nothing).

The command line extractor is documented [here](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/cmdline.html) - but with no examples on usage.

Also in the [same pointer](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/messages.html) above, there is some mention of a config file to be used with extraction, but not much expanded on.

When I run the basic command for the extractor on a dir with js files, I get only the .PO header generated but no messages.

```
$ pybabel extract   /path/to/js-dir

# Translations template for PROJECT.
# Copyright (C) 2012 ORGANIZATION
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PROJECT project.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, 2012.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PROJECT VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: EMAIL@ADDRESS\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2012-04-22 19:39+1000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Generated-By: Babel 0.9.6\n"

$
```

Here is a sample segment from a js file I'm trying to extract messages for:

```
else if(data.status == "1"){
    var follow_html = gettext('Follow');
    object.attr("class", 'button follow');
    object.html(follow_html);
    var fav = getFavoriteNumber();
    fav.removeClass("my-favorite-number");
    if(data.count === 0){
        data.count = '';
        fav.text('');
    }else{
        var fmts = ngettext('%s follower', '%s followers', data.count);
        fav.text(interpolate(fmts, [data.count]));
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it if someone can provide exact CLI options and config settings to make the extraction work, or a pointer to such.

Comment: what are the gettext/ngettext functions youre using in your js?  I'm at the same stage now - I have babel working for html & python but not js

Comment: Actually it's an OS project (Askbot) - you can check it here https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel

Comment: I figured out my problem, by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647449/serving-i18n-js-using-babel-django-jinja2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file (`babel.cfg`) with the following content:

```
[javascript:*.js]
encoding = utf-8
```

Then, do:

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg /path/to/js-dir
```

That should be enough for you to have some message strings.

BTW, you can consult the help for the `extract` command by doing:

```
pybabel extract --help
```

Comment: Sorry for being late in responding. I'm doing exactly what you have outlined and getting the exact same result shown in my question. Have you tested the command on sizable examples.

Comment: I had the same problem. Then I created a babel.cfg file containing this:
```
[javascript: **.js]
extract_messages = _
````
and now it is working!

Comment: And as an aside define a plural keyword like this: `-k "ngettext:1,2"`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and was able to get around it by disabling default keywords with babel.

```
pybabel extract -k __ -F babel.cfg --no-default-keywords /path/to/js-dir
```

You must specify at least one keyword in the command when you disable the defaults (-k [keyword]). I chose `-k __` because "__" was a pattern I was looking for.

Just use this command and replace the "__" after -k with one from your babel.cfg file.

Edit: this allows you to use your own keywords rather than gettext()

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object in as flask global and translate it with gettext

```
g.i18n = {
    'Casa' : lazy_gettext('Home'),
    'Auto' : lazy_gettext('Car'),
    'Persona' : lazy_gettext('Person')
}
```

Then add it as a variable

```
<script>
    var i18n = {{ g.i18n | tojson }}
</script>
```

and use it in JS:

```
var labelTranslate = {
                    Casa: i18n.Casa,
                    Persona: i18n.Persona,
                    Auto: i18n.Auto
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `gettext` directly in Javascript.

See: [jsgettext](http://jsgettext.sourceforge.net). It allows you to use the standard *gettext functions, including the one using contexts and/or plural forms.

It can read PO/MO files or you can import custom made JSON files instead.

See [this file](https://github.com/ZeWaren/flask-i18n-example/blob/master/static/js/scripts.js) of [this project](https://github.com/ZeWaren/flask-i18n-example) for a complete example.