# serving i18n js using babel, django, & jinja2

Tags: python, django, internationalization, jinja2, python-babel

### Using django, with jinja2 for rendering & babel for message extraction

I have some js files that need to be internationalized.  I haven't been able to figure out a syntax for extracting messages from them which would also let jinja2 render them.  Either jinja2 has to learn to read an extractable syntax, or I have to extract from something jinja2 can render.  (Or, do this another way entirely)

### Extracting

If I mark messages in the js with

```
gettext('message')
```

It extracts just fine.

### Rendering

But jinja2 won't replace gettext calls in js (I'm rendering the js templates with jinja2 before returning them) - it needs something like

```
{% trans %}message{% endtrans %}
```

But, that syntax can't be used to extract messages.

Babel is using the function extract_javascript from babel.messages to extract messages, which doesn't look equipeed to handle this type of tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like I can just do:

```
{{gettext("message")}}
```

(without defining gettext)

in the JS and babel will extract & jinja2 will replace it ok.

Watch out for quotes, though.  You can't do:

```
'{{gettext("message")}}'
```

because extract_javascript will not read it.  But, you can just put the quotes inside, as long as you render them safely:

```
{{gettext("'message'")|safe}}
```

So have your translators make sure to leave quotations wherever they find them in the original.

Comment: This translates the message, but does not work when you want to work with strings (no double/single quotes are placed around). Do you know if it is even possible?