# babel flask jinja javascript hell

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, python-babel

Is there a way for me to include flask jinja enclosed babel translations inside of my javascript file and load it in as if it was a static file? Or is the only way for me to do this to include this part of my code in the .html template file? I'm asking because I want to abstract this part of my code out so it can be reused in other areas, but if I do this, I lose the translations and am not able to obtain necessary information.

Please advice. 
I want to import javascript file but also be able to use

```
var x = {{_('translation here')}}
```

inside of my javascript file and also be able to pull out the translations via babel to be later internationalized via .po file.

Thanks! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot to make flask babel translate texts from my js file and just import the script to the html with a:

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

so I found some good links:

1. [Flask-Babel localized strings within js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355953/flask-babel-localized-strings-within-js])
2. [Babel.cfg](https://github.com/python-babel/babel/issues/71)

So I understood that I need to make my own babel.cfg file: that includes [javascript: **/**.js] in the header.

Although I did it, and executed the code:

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot
```

It still didn't translated from javascript... so for now I am putting the script in an html:

```
<html>
<script>
//my script with {{_('translating')}}
</script>
</html>
```

And including this html where I need the script with an:

```
{% include 'myscript.html' %}
```

I know it is horrible, but is the only think that is working for me now

Answer (score -2):

To use jinja notation in js you should wrap it with "":

use:

```
var x = "{{_('translation here')}}"
```

or:

```
var x = "{{gettext('translation here')}}"
```

But I think the standard way is to pass the translation from back-end:

```
from flask_babel import gettext
foo = gettext(a)
return render_template(HTML, a=a)
```